# Passing hex to bash command in C

Tags: c, linux, bash

I'm trying to port a bash script to c. I'm having trouble passing a hex string to a bash command. This is what I have so far.

```
char buffer[512];
char mp_fmt[] = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x09\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\02\x00\x01";
sprintf(buffer,"echo -e \"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x09\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\02\x00\x01\" | nc 192.168.01.22 500");
//sprintf(buffer,"echo -e \"%s\" | nc 192.168.01.22 500");
system((char *)buffer);
```

When I run this, the compiler returns this

```
test.c:7:5: warning: embedded ‘\0’ in format [-Wformat-contains-nul]
     sprintf(buffer,"echo \"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x09\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\02\x00\x01\" | nc 192.168.01.22 500");
```

But when I run it with the other sprintf that's commented out, it doesn't complain but its not working because the device isn't responding.

Also in the bash script, this is how its done and I get a response from the device.

```
echo -e "\0\0\0\0\0\x9\x1\x10\0\0\0\01\02\0\x01" | nc 192.168.01.22 500
```

Thanks for reading my long post.

Comment: Why are you porting a script to C if you are just going to call a bunch of external binaries anyway?

Comment: Because I have to do some bit shifting and I feel more comfortable doing it in c. This is just an example to get a response from the device.

Comment: I posted an answer that cleanly compiles and works. (I tested it using 'localhost' and port set to 80 using apache2 server,)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing it like this, you don't want the `0` bytes but the literal string `\0`. So,

```
sprintf(buffer, "echo \"\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\x9\\x10 [...]
```

would work.

That being said, there are a some other *issues*.

The simple one is: What is the buffer for? You don't have **any** formatting, so just use the string of your command literally!

Next: Using `echo` from C? Really? You fork 3(!) processes like this. At least, use `popen()` for nc and just `fwrite()` your input string there.

Even better: You just send some data to a socket. There is a perfecly fine `bsd sockets` API for that, no need to call ANY external tool.

**[edit]**: by using sockets yourself, you CAN send the raw `0` bytes.

**[edit2]**: some sketchup code

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

[...]

int fd;
struct sockaddr_in sin;
char mp_fmt[] = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x09\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x00\x01";

fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.22");
sin.sin_port = htons(500);

connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sin,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

write(fd, mp_fmt, 15);

shutdown(fd, SHUT_RDWR);
close(fd);
```

Comment: Thanks! I never heard of popen() before.

Comment: see my second edit for an implementation in C (untested, just for reference)

Comment: Just tried your code and it works! Now to look up everything so I can understand what's going.

Comment: btw, i would prefer `char mp_fmt[] = {0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x9,0x1,0x10,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x1,0x2,0x0,0x1};` .. just because this is *no way* a string but a sequence of bytes. compiles to the same code except you save the implicit 0 byte at the end, but is *imho* more concise.

Answer (score 0):

The warning comes because you have a null character inside the string you specified. It is expected and there's nothing you can do besides turning the warning off.

Also I'm guessing this:

```
//sprintf(buffer,"echo -e \"%s\" | nc 192.168.01.22 500");
```

should be this:

```
//sprintf(buffer,"echo -e \"%s\" | nc 192.168.01.22 500", mp_fmt);
```

In this case your device does not respond because not the **entire** string is passed in.
In C, the standard is that string are **null-terminated**. This means that any library call (such as `sprintf`), will not access memory beyond the first null-character it encounters. Thus in this case what is being written into your buffer is only the first `\x00`, and nothing else.

Comment: Well, you identify the problem correctly, but the solution is wrong. `echo` will still not accept an argument containing `0` bytes, because it's still the string terminator (in `echo`s `argv`). That's why you use the escaped form of literal `\0`.

Comment: I don't get it... in the example he gave from the bash script passing -e so the device expects the null character. In the case you gave it would pass whatever the ascii representation of literal `\0` to the device wouldn't it??

i'm confused lol could you kindly explain?

Comment: Yep, echo will send `0` bytes through the pipe to nc. the point here is: echo cannot read `0` bytes from it's argument list ... that's the reason for the escape sequence `\0` (meaning two bytes, ascii code for ``\`` and ascii code for `0`). If you want to construct a working commandline in C, you have to put the string `\0` there instead of the byte `0`. echo translates this to a `0` byte before writing it.

Comment: oh right i was confused because you didn't print -e into the buffer. it is necessary i believe for echo to interpret escaped sequences

Answer (score -2):

the posted code contains several oversights.

To keep things simple, here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{

    char buffer[512];
    char mp_fmt[] = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x09\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\02\x00\x01";

    sprintf(buffer,"echo -e \"%s\" | nc 192.168.01.22 500", mp_fmt);
    system((char *)buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No it has the same issue. It puts `0` bytes in the command line argument for `echo`. <del>`echo` will see an empty string as its first argument, because the first character is `0`.</del> -- in fact, the shell will stop parsing this at the first `0` byte...

Comment: 1) all of your data is *constant*.  You can *delete* every line but "system()", and use a string literal, instead of sprintf/buffer.  2) It doesn't solve the problem you asked about in the first place :( 3) I'm still not sure you completely understand the difference between a binary "0" (8 bits, all 0) and an ASCII "0" (8 bits, 0x30).  If you want to use "echo", you must use ASCII.  And if you want the quotes and the back-slashes passed to "echo" then you must escape them in C: `"echo -e \"\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x09\\x01\\x10\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01\\02\\x00\\x01\" | nc 192.168.01.22 500"`